# Why is it 'Er lag auf seinem panzerartig harten Rücken' instead of 'Er lag auf seinem panzerartigen harten Rücken'?

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

I'm reading Franz Kafka's [*Die Verwandlung*](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/22367/pg22367.txt). The second sentence is: 'Er lag auf seinem panzerartig harten Rücken [...]'. I think this sentence means 'He lied on his shell-like hard back [...]". In particular, 'panzerartig' seems to me as an adjective meaning shell-like ('panzer' + '-artig'). But if it's an adjective why doesn't it get an -en suffix like 'hart' does in order to agree with 'dem Rücken'? I would write this sentence as 'Er lag auf seinem panzerartigen harten Rücken [...]'; why is this wrong?

Comment: Hint: if an adjective is not inflected it is probably an adverb.

Comment: So is it "hard-like-shell back"? Can 'panzerartig' be both adverb and adjective then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes it's small things that make a difference:

> Sie wusch ihr künstliches blondes Haar.

*She washed her artificial blonde hair.*

> Sie wusch ihr künstlich blondes Haar.

*She washed her artificially blonde hair.*

Similarily, in your example:

> Er lag auf seinem panzerartig harten Rücken.

*panzerartig* describes *hart*, not the *Rücken*.

Comment: Can any adjective potentially be an adverb in German? (Sorry if this is a very stupid question...)

Comment: I can't think of any which can't at the moment.

Comment: Does the adjective describe a property that can modify another property? Then, yes. Otherwise, it would make little sense. For instance, I couldn't think of a construction that uses "rot" in this way.

Comment: @KilianFoth "Die dunkelrot gleißende Sonne ging unter". "Rot" works well as a modifier of a participle.

Comment: @user28927: The adjectives are not transformed into adverbs. They stay adjectives. In German, adjectives can describe nouns, verbs or other adjectives, thus they fulfill some of the functions where English requires adverbs.

Comment: @tofro Using participles is cheating, since they take their semantics from the underlying verbs. I don't think there is an understandable way of exhibiting an adjectival *property* X "in a red way", rather than just being X and red.

Comment: This still is about using an adjective as an adverb.

Comment: @tofro   Jedoch *dunkelrot gleißend* ist logisch unschlüssig und daher kein gutes Beispiel: *Gleißend* ist sehr, sehr hell. *Dunkelrot* ist aber eher... äh... dunkel.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Schon mal in eine Gießerei gekuckt?